# Matrix inverse problem

Tags: matrices

$M$ is a $m \times n$ matrix such that $I_{m}+MM^T$ is invertible, show that
$(I_{n}+M^TM)^{-1}=I_{n}-(I_{M}+MM^T)^{-1}M$.

I don't know how to prove this question
$$(I_{m}+MM^T)(I_{m}+MM^T)^{-1}=I_{m}$$
$$(MM^T)^{-1}(I_{m}+MM^T)(I_{m}+MM^T)^{-1}M=(M^{T})^{-1}$$
$$M^{-1}(I_{m}+MM^T)(I_{m}+MM^T)^{-1}M=I_{n}$$
When I reached this point I stopped as I don't know how to continue.
Can any one help me?

Comment: You can refer this for better formatting  and edit accordingly so that you can better help from other users -http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I fixed some of the formatting problems, but would you mind explaning what the "s.t $I_m +MM^T$" means?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect there is an error in your expression in the RHS.

However, such kind of expressions are generally derived using the [Morrison-Woodbury formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity), which is (quoted from Wikipedia)
$$(A + UCV)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}U(C^{-1}+ VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1},$$ provided $C^{-1}+ VA^{-1}U$ is invertible.

Set $A= I_n$, $U = M^T$, $V = M$, and $C = I_m$. Given that $I_m + MM^T$ is invertible, you get
$$(I_n + M^TM)^{-1} = I_n - M^T(I_m + MM^T)^{-1}M,$$
which is exactly same as your expression except an additional $M^T$ in the RHS.